# How to use expdp dumpfile as external oracle_datapump

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I couldn't use dump expdp output file in to external table with access driver.
Is it possible to use expdp output file in to external table?
Is there any special solution for this case or the structure is so different?

script :

```
CREATE TABLE item_import (
    item_id NUMBER
    , item_barcode VARCHAR2(20)
    , item_type NUMBER
    , item_title VARCHAR2(60)
    , item_subtitle VARCHAR2(60)
    , item_rating VARCHAR2(8)
    , item_rating_agency VARCHAR2(4)
    , item_release_date DATE
    , created_by NUMBER
    , creation_date DATE
    , last_updated_by NUMBER
    , last_update_date DATE)
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    ( TYPE oracle_datapump 
        DEFAULT DIRECTORY "download"  
        LOCATION ('item_export.dmp')
);
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-29913: error IN executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack?

Answer (score 1):

seems that you wrong the table definition.
Try the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE inventories_xt
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY def_dir1
    LOCATION ('inv_xt.dmp')
  )
  AS SELECT * FROM inventories;
```

Pls. Review the following:
[The ORACLE_DATAPUMP Access Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_dp_driver.htm)

Comment: this script make a dump file . I want to use dump file from expdp

Comment: mmmm.... Are you talking about sqlfile? the dump file is the file generated from expdp. sqllfile is generated with impdp....